# Agregaga mas cantones en cada llamada de la funcion php

Tags: javascript, php

Buen dia a todos, tengo una funcion que me lee desde la base de datos la lista de cantones, lo que sucede que cada vez que llamo a la funcion a parte que muestra los cantones que pertenecen a esa provincia tambien me muestra los cantones de las llamadas anteriores a la funcion de otras ciudades consultadas

```
function actCantonEmpr(prov) {
            let selectValor = prov;
            if(selectValor !== "" && selectValor != undefined) {
                $.ajax({
                    data: "provincia=" + selectValor,
                    url: './api/cantones',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#ciuEmprAct").prop('disabled', false);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, registro) {
                            $("#ciuEmprAct").append('<option value=' + registro.COD_CANT + '>' + registro.NOM_CANT + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#ciuEmprAct").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
```

Agradezco culquier ayuda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Has probado con un [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)?

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#ciuEmprAct").empty()
  $.each(data, function (key, registro) {
    $("#ciuEmprAct").append('<option value=' + registro.COD_CANT + '>' + registro.NOM_CANT + '</option>');
  });
}
```

El empty() hace desaparecer todo lo que el elemento contenga y asi se rellena de nuevo desde 0.  Diría que el problema lo tienes porque siempre estas haciendo `append` pero nunca reseteas los **option** anteriores.

Comment: whaaaaooo tienes toda la rzon gracias hermano

Comment: Cuando lo hayas probado, si esta respuesta responde a tu pregunta, recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa, gracias!